# NaN value when using Lambert Function in Python - in Enthought Canopy

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, enthought, scientific-computing

I am trying to use the Lambert function in Python to solve a problem; however I am getting   a NaN response, when using Canopy. My equation is as follows:

```
from scipy.special import lambertw

y=8.21016005323e+158

gama = -339.375260893

x = lambertw(y) + gama

print x
```

When I execute the same code in Matlab I get the value of x = 20.6524 which is the result I am looking for.

I am not sure what this NaN value is being caused by but I suspect it could be something to do with my enormous value for y. Is there any way that I can get Python to deal with this and give me the correct result?

Thanks

```
scipy.show_config()

   umfpack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
    library_dirs = ['C:\\Users\\vagrant\\src\\master-env\\libs']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:\\Users\\vagrant\\src\\master-env\\include']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
    library_dirs = ['C:\\Users\\vagrant\\src\\master-env\\libs']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:\\Users\\vagrant\\src\\master-env\\include']
openblas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
    library_dirs = ['C:\\Users\\vagrant\\src\\master-env\\libs']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:\\Users\\vagrant\\src\\master-env\\include']
blas_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
    library_dirs = ['C:\\Users\\vagrant\\src\\master-env\\libs']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:\\Users\\vagrant\\src\\master-env\\include']
mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
    library_dirs = ['C:\\Users\\vagrant\\src\\master-env\\libs']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:\\Users\\vagrant\\src\\master-env\\include']
```

Comment: You might want to post a [bug report here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/new).

Comment: @unutbu thanks for your help. I just posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an iteration in the `lambertw` code.  Apparently it is not converging when given a large argument.  (And as @unutbu's answer shows, whether or not it converges appears to depend on your configuration.)

Here's an alternative that works for (scalar) positive real arguments up to the maximum floating point value:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve


def lw(x):
    """Lambert W function, for real x >= 0."""

    def func(w, x):
        return np.log(x) - np.log(w) - w

    if x == 0:
        return 0
    if x > 2.5:
        lnx = np.log(x)
        w0 = lnx - np.log(lnx)
    elif x > 0.25:
        w0 = 0.8 * np.log(x + 1)
    else:
        w0 = x * (1.0 - x)

    return fsolve(func, w0, args=(x,))[0]
```

For example:

```
In [79]: lw(8.21016005323e+158)
Out[79]: 360.02763631519991

In [80]: np.finfo(1.0).max
Out[80]: 1.7976931348623157e+308

In [81]: lw(np.finfo(1.0).max)
Out[81]: 703.22703310477016
```

---

Here's my configuration:

```
In [87]: scipy.show_config()
atlas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_opt_info:
    extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
    extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]
atlas_blas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_opt_info:
    extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
    extra_compile_args = ['-msse3']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]
atlas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_blas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [129]: import scipy.special as special    

In [133]: y = 8.21016005323e+158

In [134]: gama = -339.375260893

In [139]: special.errprint(True)
Out[139]: 0

In [140]: special.lambertw(y) + gama
Out[140]: (20.652375422199896+0j)
```

---

Using scipy version 0.14.0:

```
In [130]: import scipy

In [131]: scipy.__version__
Out[132]: '0.14.0.dev-371b4ff'

In [146]: scipy.show_config()
umfpack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_threads_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'ptf77blas', 'ptcblas', 'atlas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas', '/usr/lib/atlas-base']
    define_macros = [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"3.8.4\\""')]
    language = f77
    include_dirs = ['/usr/include/atlas']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['ptf77blas', 'ptcblas', 'atlas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib/atlas-base']
    define_macros = [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"3.8.4\\""')]
    language = c
    include_dirs = ['/usr/include/atlas']
atlas_blas_threads_info:
    libraries = ['ptf77blas', 'ptcblas', 'atlas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib/atlas-base']
    define_macros = [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"3.8.4\\""')]
    language = c
    include_dirs = ['/usr/include/atlas']
openblas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'ptf77blas', 'ptcblas', 'atlas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas', '/usr/lib/atlas-base']
    define_macros = [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"3.8.4\\""')]
    language = f77
    include_dirs = ['/usr/include/atlas']
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your suggestion and it still failed. I am using Python with the Enthought Canopy Environment. When I check the scipy version it returns 0.13.3 which came prepackaged with Canopy (installed yesterday). Do you think that Canopy could be causing this?

Comment: I get `(nan+0j)` for `lambertw(8.21016005323e+158)` with scipy '0.15.0.dev-7ce6faf'.  There is an iteration in the lambertw code, which apparently is not converging.  Call `scipy.special.errprint(True)` before calling `lambertw` to see relevant warnings.

Comment: I just tried using it with Scipy 0.9.0 on a separate machine and it works fine

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I did as you suggested and I have three errors; too slow convergence (failed to converge), overflow (floating point overflow) and domain error (floating point invalid value). Any idea what these mean?

Comment: @allankey: It might be interesting if you and @WarrenWeckesser post `scipy.show_config()`.

Comment: @unutbu: I added the output of `scipy.show_config()` to my answer.